Installing Ubuntu Server on HP Probook 6360b
I've been trying to install Ubuntu server on a HP Probook 6360b. I created a bootable USB with Rufus and I've been able to successfully install it, however whenever I try to boot, I get the error BootDevice Not Found, please install an operating system on your hard disk.
I suspected this was related to the BIOS settings, but these are my settings.


I created the bootable USB with Rufus, and have tried the different partitioning methods.

Be aware that rufus allows you to reformat the ISO during write, and if you use these options you need to select options that will work on your intended device, plus use an updated rufus that will reformat ISOs correctly (ie. release of Ubuntu & rufus version need to match).  I'd suggest just simple cloning of ISO to install media; as that will install on legacy, uEFI & Secure-boot uEFI devices (I believe that's called dd method on rufus; but sorry I don't use that app).  Being specific as to what Ubuntu Server product/release you're using & rufus version may help us to help you.

Are you using a Ubuntu Server image suitable for your device? as Ubuntu Server comes in various architectures/releases & options, but you gave no details except 'Ubuntu Server'.

@guiverc I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 Live Server (AMD 64) and I'm using Rufus 4.5. I tried burning it with both the DD method and the other one (Can't remember which)

Have you tried pressing F9 during boot before "operating system not found"

HP seems to want to boot "Windows Boot Manager". Many with HP say they go into UEFI settings, not one time boot menu, & change Ubuntu entry to be first. Make sure you installed in UEFI boot mode & system is set to boot in UEFI mode, not old BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.

@oldfred I attached pictures of my boot options. There’s no setting here for ‘Windows Boot Manager’ or ‘Ubuntu’, even after installation.

What does OS boot manager show. If you click on it does it have more entries? Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HP-BIOSCFG-For-Linux-6.6

@oldfred OS boot manager doesn’t show anything. I can’t click on it to expand options or anything

I suspect it is because of your bios, see this https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/ish_3053911-2842957-16

@amar the laptop does not work with WiFi, so I can't update the BIOS. I tried creating a drive from another laptop, but it's Acer so HPQFlash didn't run

usually there is a network cable port in wifi or rouer. Connect it with cable.
